# Выделение потока и обработка исключений C# (Win.Form)

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, исключения

Имеется событие после нажатия кнопки:

```
private void connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            loadingBackgroundPanel.Show();
            loadingLinePanel.Show();
            pictureBox2.Hide();
            statusTextBox.Text = "Подключение...";
            SqlConnection Test = new SqlConnection(conString);
            try
            {
                Test.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                statusTextBox.Text = "Ошибка \r\n 1. Нет подкл. к интернету \r\n 2. SQL сервер не запущен";
                loadingBackgroundPanel.Hide();
                loadingLinePanel.Hide();;
                pictureBox2.Show();
            }
            if (Test.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                this.Hide();
                MainForm Main = new MainForm();
                Main.Show();
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Проблема в том, что во время обработки исключения `try` `catch` главный (GUI) поток останавливается из-за чего происходят следующие сложности:

1. `statusTextBox.Text = "Подключение...";` - не присваивает значение, даже учитывая, что эта строка находится выше обработки исключения.
2. Останавливается весь интерфейс - нет анимаций, нельзя закрыть программу правильно.

Естественно правильным решение было бы выделить отдельный поток для:

```
SqlConnection Test = new SqlConnection(conString);
            try
            {
                Test.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                statusTextBox.Text = "Ошибка \r\n 1. Нет подкл. к интернету \r\n 2. SQL сервер не запущен";
                loadingBackgroudPanel.Hide();
                loadingLinePanel.Hide();
                pictureBox2.Show();
            }
```

Но не знаю как это правильно и грамотно реализовать. В процессе поиска информации столкнулся с `async task`, `async void`, `Task.Run(()=>fun())`, `await`, запустался и опустил руки..
Кодер начинающий, особо не ругайте, пытался разобраться, но не смог...

Comment: _status.Text = "Подключение..."; - не присваивает значение_ - а что такое `status`? Почему бы не дать нормальное говорящее имя этой переменной (и всем остальным)? Например, `statusLabel`. По вашему коду _очень_ сложно судить, где у вас ошибка, потому что _совершенно_ непонятно, что означают все эти переменные: `loading_B`, `loading_L`...

Comment: Так как код выполняется в потоке GUI, контролы не будут обновляться, пока метод не завершится. Естественно, присвоение значений гуевым контролам произойдёт только после этого. Визуально интерфейс тормозит, _фризится_. Правильное решение - использовать асинхронные вызовы там где они есть. Или запускать длительные действия в другом потоке/задаче.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо за замечания, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашёл такое:

```
private async void connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadingBackgroudPanel.Show();
            loadingLinePanel.Show();
            pictureBox2.Hide();
            statusTextBox.Text = "Подключение...";
            SqlConnection Test = new SqlConnection(conString);
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => Test.Open());
            }
            catch
            {
                statusTextBox.Text = "Ошибка \r\n 1. Нет подкл. к интернету \r\n 2. SQL сервер не запущен";
                loadingBackgroundPanel.Hide();
                loadingLinePanel.Hide();
                pictureBox2.Show();
            }
            if (Test.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                this.Hide();
                MainForm Main = new MainForm();
                Main.Show();
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Добавил `async` в начале функции и метод `await Task.Run(() =>fun())`

Теперь возникла проблема с обработкой исключений...

`try` `catch` обрабатывают исключения верно, код выполняется правильно, но Visual Studio вечно останавливает приложение с ошибкой после `Test.Open()`. Проблема явно в обработке исклключения в том потоке, где выполняется `Test.Open()`

P.S. Ошибка в таймауте подключения, вызываю сам для исключения.

Игнорировать или разобраться?

Comment: Какая именно СУБД используется? А вернее, какой провайдер? Нет ли там метода `OpenAsync()`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, 
> MS SQL
> Есть, он работает, но разницы при его использовании я не заметил. Если вы предлагаете его использовать без `await Task.run`, это тоже работает, но интерфейс всё равно подвисает... Поэтому это пока является оптимальным решением, так как всё работает плавно.

Comment: `await Test.OpenAsync();` - использовать так. Обязательно с `await`. При этом не нужен `Task.Run`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Обманул вас. 1. Если мы используем `OpenAsync()` без параметра `async` в функции и `await` перед ним, то метод просто не работает. (подвисание перед запуском метода никуда не делось)
2. Если просто уберём `Task.Run()` и заменим `Open()` на `OpenAsync()` (как вы посоветовали), то ошибка будет та же, `try` `catch` так же обрабатывают исключение, но не убирают ошибку (как и в моём ответе). P.S. Без использования потоков ошибка не вывадиться, исключение обрабатывается. Может мне просто игнорировать ошибку в Visual?

Comment: И как же меня лично задолбало никчёмное использование `Refresh`. Постоянно вижу его вызов в десятках и сотнях тем на SO и других форумах. Что-то то тормозит? Воткнём `Refresh`. Что-то не работает - `Refresh`. Вываливается исключение - `Refresh`... В документации же описано, что он делает, этот метод. Так почему его пихают куда не следует?! Простите, выговорился...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Да, извините, это был временный костыль до использования мультипоточного выполнения. Понимаю, исправил.

Comment: Если использовать `await Test.OpenAsync();`, то весь код до его вызова должен отработать и графические контролы обновятся. То есть `status.Text = "Подключение...";` должно сработать. А тот код, который после `OpenAsync`, естественно, будет ждать, пока завершится подключение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да так именно и происходит, всё работает. Но проблема именно в ошибке, которая происходит после `OpenAsync()`, которая останавливает программу и которая не игнорируется, учитывая что метод находиться в `try` `catch`. А, так, большое спасибо за, что откликнулись.