# Движение созданных контролов picturebox в таймере

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Создаю новые PictureBox, хочу, чтобы они сдвигались влево. Когда я помещаю функцию Draw в таймер, то происходит только создание новых картинок, а движения нет. Причём, если переменные pUp и pBot инициализировать как глобальные, то данные picturebox'ы будут двигаться вверх и вниз, т.к. у координаты Y рандомное значение. Как это исправить?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace FlappyBird
{
public partial class GameForm : Form
{
    Graphics g;
    bool jumping = false;//прыжок
    int pipeSpeed = 5;//скорость передвижения блоков
    int gravity = 5;//скорость прыжка
    int Inscore = 0;
    int stp = 283;//Стартовая позиция труб
    Random r = new Random();
    PictureBox[] pipe = new PictureBox[1000];

    public GameForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Draw()
    {

        Refresh();
        int pUY = r.Next(-60, 0);//позиция верхней трубы по Y
        int pBY = r.Next(277, 352);//позиция нижней трубы по Y
        //прорисовка труб сверху
        PictureBox pUp = new PictureBox();
        pUp.Image = pipeUp.Image;
        pUp.Location = new Point(stp, pUY);
        pUp.Size = new Size(53, 241);
       //прорисовка труб снизу
        PictureBox pBot = new PictureBox();
        pBot.Image = pipeBottom.Image;
        pBot.Location = new Point(stp, pBY);
        pBot.Size = new Size(53, 182);
        if (pipeBottom.Left < -10 && pipeUp.Left < -10)
        {
            Controls.Add(pUp);
            Controls.Add(pBot);
            pUp.Left -= pipeSpeed;//сдвиг влево
            pBot.Left -= pipeSpeed;//сдвиг влево
        }
```

Comment: По поводу Refresh - [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978974/Выделение-потока-и-обработка-исключений-c-win-form/979429#comment1646963_979429)

Comment: Вы показали огрызок кода. Сложно по куску судить о целом. / Вы пишете, что Draw поместили в таймер. Ну всё верно: в этом методе у вас создаются _новые_ пикчабоксы. Вам следует сперва создать нужное количество контролов и поместить их в коллекцию. А потом по тику таймера двигать их, пробегаясь по коллекции.

Comment: Хорошо, а как примерно нужно реализовывать? Контролы нужно задать в цикле for, а движение созданных контролов нужно реализовывать циклом foreach внутри for. Верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что делает функция `Refresh`?

Скорее всего дело в том, что у тебя создаются сначала объекты

```
PictureBox pUp = new PictureBox();
...
PictureBox pBot = new PictureBox();
```

а потом ты в

```
if (pipeBottom.Left < -10 && pipeUp.Left < -10)
```

двигаешь только что созданные объекты, а не те, которые были раньше.

P.S Лучше добавить больше комментариев, кода, которым пользуется `Draw()` и изменить нейминг переменных. Запомнить, что такое `stp`, `pBY` и т.д крайне сложно.